# c++ multithread - Signal processor thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, signals

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/sigprocmask.html

Documentation show the example where all signals that need to `wait` are store at the global scope variable (filled at main() **before** signal thread started.
At the example signal thread started **after** `SIG_BLOCK` blocking signals.

Is it correct and will not cause some undefined behavior or crashes, if I will create my signal thread **before** `SIG_BLOCK` blocking signals at the main() and then I will block signals for all other newly created threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the signal thread explicitly blocks the signals it will eventually wait on with `sigwait`, then it will be safe.

For example, the following two flow examples are both safe:

```
main:
  create_signal_thread() // Inherits mask from main, so signals are not blocked.
  block_signals()        
  create_more_threads()  // Inherit mask from main, so signals are blocked.

signal_thread:
  block_signals()        // Must block signals, as this thread will wait on them.
  sigwait()              // Behavior is defined.
```

and

```
main:
  block_signals()        
  create_signal_thread() // Inherits mask from main, so signals are blocked.
  create_more_threads()  // Inherit mask from main, so signals are blocked.

signal_thread:
  sigwait()              // Behavior is defined.
```

However, this example would not be safe:

```
main:
  create_signal_thread() // Inherits mask from main, so signals are not blocked.
  block_signals()        
  create_more_threads()  // Inherit mask from main, so signals are blocked.

signal_thread:
  sigwait()              // Behavior is undefined.
```

Here is the relevant excerpt from [`sigwait`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sigwait.html):

> The signals defined by set will been blocked at the time of the call to `sigwait();` otherwise the behaviour is undefined. The effect of `sigwait()` on the signal actions for the signals in set is unspecified.

Comment: thanks, currently, I use the 3 variant, but before calling `sigwait()` I am `sigfillset(&set);` and only then `sigwait(&set, &sig);` Seems, this is ok and behavior is defined?

Comment: As long as you invoke `pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, NULL)` within the signal handler thread before `sigwait(&set, &sig)`, then you should not observe undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks, currently, I does not do that. I thought that if I will block all signals at `signal thread` as a result sigwait will not receive any signals.

Comment: `SIG_BLOCK` prevents the signal from being delivered  until it is later unblocked, leaving it in a _pending_ state.  [`sigwait()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sigwait.html) only functions on _pending_ signals.